# Realtek RTL8188CE wireless is slow

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, realtek

The wireless used to be just fine now is dead slow.

How i should troubleshoot this issue any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Is this the same as your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/205575/12-10-x64-rtl8188ce-intermittent-slow-internet-connection - this ubuntuforums thread also looks relevant: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2075387&page=2

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the solution to your problem. Realtek has Linux drivers for RTL8188CE. http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE

Comment: Thanks but the driver doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Wicd network manager, just connect to your network and if it still doesn't work check Preferences -> Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Realtek released another driver this month 07.02.2013
For me this driver is finally working fine. I have no more connection problems.
But important is:
You have to delete any configs that you might have created for example

```
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192.conf
```

The parameter are no longer valid with the new driver and if you don't delete the old config you are not able to load the new driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can change your card settings to work faster. the guide is in Hebrew, if you need, use Google to translate all the page. All the comments may help also (:

http://www.fxp.co.il/showthread.php?t=9983282