# How do I get the same Wi-Fi speed under Ubuntu as under Windows?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.10 x64 - RTL8188CE - Intermittent/Slow Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205575/12-10-x64-rtl8188ce-intermittent-slow-internet-connection)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8 on my laptop. In Windows, using wireless connection, average speed and ping to google.com is 60kBps and less than 25 ms, but in Ubuntu, top internet speed only reach 10 kBps and ping reach 12000 ms, that's happen not only on browser but on entire system like `gwibber` or `apt-get`. How do I make it as fast as on Windows?

Note:
My WiFi hotspot is a PC running latest version of connectify.

Update:
Everytime wifi connected to connectify hotspot, I always get this message:

> Network service discovery disabled.
>   Your current network has a .local
>   domain, which is not recommended and incompatible with the Avahi
>   network service discovery. The service has been disabled.

Update:
`sudo lshw -c network` give me this:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:2f:68:f1:b3:1e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.5.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.251.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: c8:9c:dc:10:fa:47
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0900000-f0900fff memory:f0a04000-f0a07fff
```

and `lsmod` give me this:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31423  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    63493  1 
joydev                 17161  0 
snd_hda_intel          32515  3 
parport_pc             31968  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec         111547  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80163  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
i915                  457181  3 
rtl8192ce              52841  0 
rtl8192c_common        47075  1 rtl8192ce
coretemp               13168  0 
ppdev                  12817  0 
rtlwifi                64137  1 rtl8192ce
btusb                  17986  0 
uvcvideo               71277  0 
psmouse                84843  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51255  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
drm_kms_helper         47303  1 i915
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
videobuf2_core         32070  1 uvcvideo
drm                   238768  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
videodev               95841  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
bnep                   17707  2 
rfcomm                 37276  12 
mac80211              461161  3 rtl8192ce,rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi
kvm_intel             126745  0 
kvm                   357806  1 kvm_intel
bluetooth             183228  22 btusb,bnep,rfcomm
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
cfg80211              175375  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
snd                    61991  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
sparse_keymap          13658  0 
video                  18847  1 i915
mac_hid                13037  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12756  1 uvcvideo
mei                    35796  0 
videobuf2_memops       13184  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
wmi                    18590  0 
soundcore              14599  1 snd
microcode              18209  0 
serio_raw              13031  0 
snd_page_alloc         14036  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lpc_ich                16925  0 
binfmt_misc            17260  1 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12445  0 
usbhid                 41702  0 
hid                    82142  2 hid_generic,usbhid
r8169                  55976  0
```

Comment: In either case the speed is very low. Why?

Comment: Yes, that's why I need some solution, because I'm planning to fully migrate to Ubuntu.

Comment: we need some details of your hardware.. edit your question and include result of `sudo lshw -c network`, `lsmod`

Comment: @Web-E done....

Comment: I have followed these method and using compat wireless driver, none of those work for me.