# internet connection issue with rtl8192ce / toshiba satellite / realtek wireless card

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek, toshiba-satellite, rtl8192ce

**Update- I tried turning off the wireless card firmware power saving feature and now I stay connected when I'm within approximately 15 ft of the router.  Prior to switching to Ubuntu I had reliable connection at least twice that far and all of my other wifi items still connect at beyond 30 ft.  Prior to disabling the firmware power saving feature I could not stay connected within close proximity to the router.  Because this seems to have helped I am going to look for the instructions I saw on how to disable another power saving feature for the wireless card.  I'll post both the command that I used already and the other command once I find them again- they were both in the same post.

**update: the commands I ran were:

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce ips=0 fwlps=0
```

....but they don't seem to get a reliable signal from more than about 15 feet from the router. Again, numerous other wifi devices get the signal over 30 feet away and this computer did as well until Ubuntu.  I will need to keep at this until I find a fix because I can't only use my laptop in the room with the router.  :)

I'm less than 24 hours into Linux/Ubuntu. I'm on 12.04 LTS. (when this was first posted)

I can connect to the internet just fine at first.  But within somewhere between 2 minutes and 20 minutes I am no longer able to view new web pages although I still seem to be connected to the router.  Disconnecting and reconnecting fixes every time.

I ran a few things that it seems likely will be asked of me having looked at other similar posts. Please let me know if you need anything else.

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ modinfo rtl8192ce
filename: /lib/modules/3.8.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
firmware: rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
firmware: rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU.bin
firmware: rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
description: Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license: GPL
author: Larry Finger <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author: Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author: lizhaoming <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion: B41EC2D43683C181DF50FB6
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008176sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008177sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008178sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008191sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends: rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,mac80211
intree: Y
vermagic: 3.8.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm: swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
(bool)
parm: ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
(bool)
parm: swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
(bool)
parm: fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
(bool)
parm: debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
```

---

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8192ce 58733 0 
rtl8192c_common 49561 1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi 81225 1 rtl8192ce
mac80211 630977 3 rtl8192ce,rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi
cfg80211 525326 2 rtlwifi,mac80211
```

---

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ dmesg | grep rtl 
[ 8.417968] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
[ 8.536512] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 8.536688] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 66.194356] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
```

---

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ dmesg | grep -e rtl -e 80211 -e wlan
[ 7.568257] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 8.417968] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
[ 8.536512] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 8.536688] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 15.922653] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 15.922919] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 20.918113] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 20.949695] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 21.124423] wlan0: authenticated
[ 21.125057] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 21.137780] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=3)
[ 21.137944] wlan0: associated
[ 21.137957] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 61.948146] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 61.984778] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: EC
[ 66.194356] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 68.867214] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 72.213557] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 72.245459] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 72.247442] wlan0: authenticated
[ 72.249150] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 72.260906] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 72.261069] wlan0: associated
[ 72.261079] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 264.765119] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 264.807585] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 272.105040] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 272.129333] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 272.134530] wlan0: authenticated
[ 272.136727] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 272.146802] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 272.146965] wlan0: associated
[ 525.021020] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 525.059848] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 532.345262] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 532.374166] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 532.384738] wlan0: authenticated
[ 532.385642] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 532.397310] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 532.397492] wlan0: associated
[ 1216.554482] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1216.592606] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1223.882736] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 1223.910563] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 1223.912130] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1223.914939] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 1223.927597] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1223.927763] wlan0: associated
[ 1454.312051] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1454.349503] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1461.644094] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[ 1461.671809] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 1461.673382] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1461.675268] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[ 1461.684063] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1461.684244] wlan0: associated
[35484.428990] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[35484.468906] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[35491.759011] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[35491.780024] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[35491.782198] wlan0: authenticated
[35491.785601] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[35491.794285] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[35491.794449] wlan0: associated
[37449.699230] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[37449.736487] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[37457.013415] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[37457.042859] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[37457.246099] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 2/3)
[37457.449840] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 3/3)
[37457.653569] wlan0: authentication with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 timed out
[37463.950874] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[37463.981838] wlan0: direct probe to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[37464.185118] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 2/3)
[37464.190428] wlan0: authenticated
[37464.193301] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[37464.207439] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[37464.207615] wlan0: associated
[37840.014512] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[37840.056904] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[37841.054674] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[37841.086562] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[37841.088008] wlan0: authenticated
[37841.090148] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[37841.098872] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[37841.099053] wlan0: associated
[38211.316937] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[38211.363949] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[38212.346797] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[38212.378593] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38212.581951] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 2/3)
[38212.785688] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 3/3)
[38212.989440] wlan0: authentication with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 timed out
[38218.936084] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[38218.966382] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38218.967921] wlan0: authenticated
[38218.969692] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38218.978328] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[38218.978481] wlan0: associated
[38526.055464] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[38526.097918] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[38533.389005] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[38533.413065] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38533.415046] wlan0: authenticated
[38533.415903] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38533.426599] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[38533.426760] wlan0: associated
[38696.325529] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[38700.082256] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[38707.355454] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[38707.386868] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38707.582609] wlan0: authenticated
[38707.586215] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38707.618877] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[38707.619059] wlan0: associated
[38986.465625] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[38986.513453] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[38993.756647] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[38993.779645] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38993.784645] wlan0: authenticated
[38993.787150] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[38993.801117] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[38993.801302] wlan0: associated
[39081.401645] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[39081.454816] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[39088.734718] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[39088.761295] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39088.767490] wlan0: authenticated
[39088.768840] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39088.777552] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[39088.777716] wlan0: associated
[39092.028037] wlan0: deauthenticated from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (Reason: 15)
[39092.064711] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[39093.447683] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[39093.479187] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39093.484799] wlan0: authenticated
[39093.486795] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39093.495490] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[39093.495659] wlan0: associated
[39897.730449] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[39897.793459] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[39905.060679] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[39905.086931] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39905.089198] wlan0: authenticated
[39905.090500] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[39905.104216] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[39905.104380] wlan0: associated
[40366.542055] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[40366.589901] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[40367.545515] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[40367.577591] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[40367.580260] wlan0: authenticated
[40367.581182] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[40367.589856] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[40367.590031] wlan0: associated
[42816.822883] wlan0: deauthenticating from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 by local choice (reason=3)
[42816.830956] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[42817.418361] wlan0: authenticate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70
[42817.449996] wlan0: send auth to 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[42817.453152] wlan0: authenticated
[42817.453443] wlan0: associate with 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (try 1/3)
[42817.462272] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[42817.462457] wlan0: associated
```

---

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
Type: Wired
Driver: r8169
State: unavailable
Default: no
HW Address: 70:542:5F:F8:5E

Capabilities:
Carrier Detect: yes
Speed: 100 Mb/s

Wired Properties
Carrier: off

- Device: wlan0 [HOME-E272] ---------------------------------------------------
Type: 802.11 WiFi
Driver: rtl8192ce
State: connected
Default: yes
HW Address: 24:EC:99:EA:01:F1

Capabilities:
Speed: 65 Mb/s

Wireless Properties
WEP Encryption: yes
WPA Encryption: yes
WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
*HOME-E272: Infra, 5C:57:1A7:E2:70, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 68 WPA WPA2
Tonya: Infra, 00:1D486:20, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA WPA2
HOME-0EA2: Infra, 00:1D3:4F:0E:A0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
BlueSkyWireless: Infra, 00:25:3C:C4:ED:51, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA
2WIRE373: Infra, 98:2C:BE:06:14:49, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA
Owner24: Infra, 00:26:F2:FE:EE:98, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA WPA2
2WIRE226: Infra, 3C:EA:4F:79:34:29, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 72 WPA
ATT376: Infra, B8:16:19:3F:C6:E0, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
TriqWave: Infra, A0:21:B7:A1:3A:26, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA WPA2
davis567: Infra, F8:ED:A5:AA:68:70, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65 WPA WPA2
veganaisse_EXT: Infra, 20:E5:2A:57:11:0B, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65
HPC410a.464F20: Ad-Hoc, 02:26:26:91:94:90, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 65
Brenda network: Infra, 84:C9:B2:54:92:AD, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA
2WIRE854: Infra, 60:C3:97:42:1F:51, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2


IPv4 Settings:
Address: 10.0.0.9
Prefix: 24 (255.255.255.0)
Gateway: 10.0.0.1


DNS: 75.75.75.75
DNS: 75.75.76.76
```

This run of nm-tool (above) was while I had no use-able internet connection although it appears I'm connected to the router in some way.

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ iw reg get
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0)
nathaniel@nathaniel-Satellite-C875:~$ lspci -vvvnn -d10ec:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8212]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at c2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Also, although I had some difficulty getting 12.04 to install (had issues with grub/boot files) I am willing to switch to 13 if it will solve this issue. Regarding 13 and the 9 month support- does that mean I will have to install a new version of Ubuntu in 9 months to continue getting security/other updates? Or will 13 then just become the new LTS? I know that's a very basic question but hey, I'm a Linux noob!

Comment: Hi @Mitch, did you straighten out the display of my 'reports'?  If so did you do that by entering them as 'code'? Thanks

Comment: That's right entered as code using <$>.

Comment: I have access to a mini-pc that uses the same rtl8192ce driver and noticed similar issues. Connecting (and keeping the connection alive!) works when used with my Android phone as AP. Although a distant AP does associate, there is no connection (100% packet loss). My suspicion are the regulatory settings, so can you add the output of `iw reg get` to your question? It should show something like `country US: DFS-UNSET (2402 - ...`

Comment: @CoolestUsername Can you also add `lspci -vvvnn -d10ec:` to your question? If you have multiple Realtek devices, only copy the part related to the wireless adapter. What about this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1171708

Comment: @Lekensteyn done.

Comment: @CoolestUsername Yep, I have the same network device (10ec:8176). Disabling the power savings as described at http://askubuntu.com/q/205575/6969 did not help for me, but YMMV.

Comment: @CoolestUsername If possible, please add the output of `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | awk 'b&&/^BSS/{exit}/5c:57:1a:d7:e2:70/{b=1}b{print}'` to your question. This command shows information about the networks that your WLAN card sees, and limits the output to your network. I am looking for relations with: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60713

Comment: @Lekensteyn -  I followed your link bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1171708 , downloaded, compiled, and installed the driver.  Right now I'm at a location where the router is right next to me but as soon as I'm able I'll check if it fixed the issue.

Comment: sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 20 will give you a better range

Comment: also, sudo modprobe rtl8192ce should do it, power management should be off by default.

Comment: I tried *everything* to get the rtl8192ce working on my Lenovo T530. After wasting a ton of time I found an actual solution: a screwdriver and an Intel wireless card. Works better than the Realtek ever did in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 retry 20
```

to get a better range out of your laptop. This will increase the retry for failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop start crashing with the latest kernels (3.5.0-47-generic and 48 too)
so I downloaded the drivers direct from Realtek. I was worried since they had listed there kernels pre and post 2.6.24. That is a bit old. However 3.5.0-47 is post...

But having enough with the complete crash and need to reboot, I gave it a try.

And I am glad I did!

Here is the [page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) to the driver.

Extract then follow the readme. I think you need to this for every new kernel update, as it updated the current kernel only.

Answer (score 0):

get the latest drivers then select 2nd antena, apparently rtl8192ce chipset supports dual-antenna-wifi, but some manufacturers only build one physical antenna into their products this is the reason for your bad reception, just do:

```
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce ant_sel=2
```

and save it in the config:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8192ce ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf'
```